# detect unacknowledged UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, uiapplication

It seems that

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

and

`didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`

are only triggered if the user acknowledges the UILocalNotification, for example by swiping the slider or touching the entry in iOS's Notification pull-down.

Is there any way to tell that a UILocalNotification has gone off if the user ignores the UILocalNotification and re-enters the app by simply clicking on the app icon?

I should mention that this really only applies to repeating notifications because the firing of non-repeating notifications can be detected by observing the total count.  That is, when they fire, the vanish from `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]`.

I'm looking for something like..

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unacknowledgedLocalNotifications]`

Alas, I can't find anything like it.

Comment: If your notification is *not* in `scheduledLocalNotifications`, it is no longer scheduled so it must have fired.

Comment: 'just edited the question.  I actually had that text in there but wanted to keep things as simple as I could (i.e. less text).

Comment: I've got a feeling that what you want doesn't exist, but this would make a *great* feature request with Apple's bug reporter.

Comment: Thanks :)  Sadly I've filed a few "great feature ideas" with Apple and always get ignored.

Comment: Me too, but I still do it! And I stick with it: even when they say I'm wrong, I keep after them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can check your scheduled notifications inside `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]`. To find out if a scheduled repeating notification has fired access the `fireDate` property to see what was the initial date set for the notification. Then check the `repeatInterval` property.

So there you have 2 variables, one is the initial `NSDate`, lets say `2013-05-08 12:00` and second is the repeat interval, lets say daily. And by doing a `[NSDate date]` you will get the current date which where I'm located (in Sweden) is now `2013-05-09 22:45`. So this means that there is one notification the user has not acted on.

So you will need to create a method that will take these arguments and then iterate from the initial date to see how many notifications that have been missed until the current datetime.

You will find `NSCalendar`s [dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a) useful.

Comment: Truth be told, I was in the process of implementing this and thought that Apple _had_ to have taken care of this to save me a bunch of lines.  Thanks!

Comment: Me too, unfortunately you have to implement it yourself. It's a little work but it's working out nicely.

Comment: Any reason you're using NSCalendars and Components and not simply NSDate's timeIntervalSinceNow?  So that you can so something like `for (UILocalNotification *uiln in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) { if ([uiln.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) // do some stuff }`

Comment: @arigold Because the fireDate property is static, hence it does not dynamically change after each repeat.

Comment: @PeterWarbo what if the repeat interval is none...so uiln wont be available in the array...then how do i get that uiln?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has likely since moved on, but I'd like to share my solution to this problem. (Sorry about the long variables names...)

The idea is simple: always keep the fireDate in the future.

-every time didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or didReceiveLocalNotification is invoked, simply cancel your current notification and reschedule a new one with a fireDate one interval unit in the future

-When your app launches iterate through all scheduled notifications, if the fireDate is not in the future you know that it was ignored

In my case, the notifications have a weekly repeat interval. I first reschedule any acknowledged notifications in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification* localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotif != nil)
    {
        [NotificationsHelper rescheduleNotification:localNotif];
    }
}
```

And also in didReceiveLocalNotification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *) notification
{
   [NotificationsHelper rescheduleNotification:notification];
}
```

At App Launch I check all notifications for any with a fireDate in the past:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self checkLocalNotifications:application];
}
```

Code for my "checkLocalNotifications" function:

```
- (void) checkLocalNotifications:(UIApplication *) application
{
    UIApplication*  app        = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray*        eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    for (int i = 0; i < [eventArray count]; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification* notification = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([NotificationsHelper wasWeeklyRepeatingNotificationIgnored:notification])
        {
            [NotificationsHelper rescheduleNotification:notification];

            NSLog(@"NotificationWasIgnored: %@ %@",notification.alertAction, notification.alertBody );
        }
    }
}
```

Code for my "wasWeeklyRepeatingNotificationIgnored" function:

```
+ (BOOL) wasWeeklyRepeatingNotificationIgnored:(UILocalNotification*) the_notification
{
    BOOL    result;
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

    // FireDate is earlier than now
    if ([the_notification.fireDate compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        result = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        result = FALSE;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Code for my "rescheduleNotification" function:

```
+ (void) rescheduleNotification:(UILocalNotification*) the_notification
{
    UILocalNotification* new_notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary* userinfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [new_notification setUserInfo:userinfo];
    [new_notification setRepeatInterval:the_notification.repeatInterval];
    [new_notification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
    [new_notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [new_notification setAlertAction:the_notification.alertAction];
    [new_notification setAlertBody:the_notification.alertBody];
    [new_notification setRepeatCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
    [new_notification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:the_notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber];

    NSCalendar*       gregorian         = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                                       fromDate:the_notification.fireDate];

    NSInteger weekday   = [weekdayComponents weekday];
    NSDate*   next_week = [self addDay:weekday toHourMinute:the_notification.fireDate];

    [new_notification setFireDate:next_week];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:new_notification];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:the_notification];
}
```

Comment: Again, this will only work with repeating UILNs because otherwise, the UILN won't exist in the system. That is, iOS deletes non-repeating UILNs that fire.

Comment: Incidentally, never apologize about long variable names.. IMHO, it's waaay better to overshoot how descriptive your names are.  And nice code.

Answer (score 0):

**If your UILocalNotifications increment the application icon badge number** (i.e. the number in the red circle on the top right of the app's icon), then there is a *ridiculously simple* way to check for unacknowledged UILocalNotifications: just check what the current `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{        
    int unacknowledgedNotifs = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    NSLog(@"I got %d unacknowledged notifications", unacknowledgedNotifs);
    //do something about it...

    //You might want to reset the count afterwards:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

}
```

Comment: badge doesnt change if user dismisses notification from tray.